# Alternatives to present multiple location information on a map

Tags: typography, text, design-principles, information-graphics, data-visualisation

I have a client who thinks that there really needs to be a comma between the name of the school, and the public school zone number (CSD#). I would love a second opinion from a design perspective. Doesn't the contrasting weight and size of the CSD# separate it from the school name, making it unnecessary to place a comma or parenthesis in between? Any alternatives?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't matter what anyone here thinks... it's the client's project. For me, they get what they want. I, personally would use a colon, vertical bar, parenthesis, or change the color of the CSD#.

Answer (score 1):

From a design perspective I agree with you that the contrasting text weight differentiates the two sections. To satisfy the client, rather than a comma which I think will look out of place, you can try a different character, such as this character "|" (I don't know what it is called but you find it on the \ key),  or a dash or en-dash in front of the –CSD.  Either of these will look better than a comma design-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference in font formatting could work, but yes a client might expect something more obvious. Why not use larger pins instead of dots and put the CSD inside? Make both these and the text in a stronger color, not necessarily black. This way you don't need to add extra characters to separate what looks like too much text already, and you will construct a more *infographic-style* map.

[image]

Comment: I am just guessing here, but the problem with placing the CSD information within a pin is that it is unlikely that the CSD's include only a single school site.  It is much more likely that each of the school sites has a single location within the much boundaries of a particular CSD. It could be argued that using the CSD info inside of a pin could make the map seem less accurate.

Comment: Yes, but since we don't know all the facts and can only guess, I gave the OP a different perspective on this. He could use this or adapt or help see this differently. My general point is there is TOO MUCH text on his original artwork. I would simplify somehow and this is one option, if it works. What's the point of a map after all if you fill it with overlaid text?

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, from a design perspective you've got it. Clear differentiation to me. From your client's perspective, they are likely coming from an academic background, or at some point they had a boss that insisted on doing things one way.

I run into this often with medical clients on punctuation. My solution for not sacrificing a design is to quote a contradictory source. Here's [a link](https://www.englishforums.com/English/PunctuationAdvancedDegrees/xgwjc/post.htm) citing to NOT use punctuation for medical terms, yet I know the defacto Associated Press (AP) Style Guide clearly calls for it (my copywriters tell me all the time!!).

WHAT I FIND WORKS BEST, is to specifically inform your client of this gray area and why your design works better. This is important because they often will have to get your work approved in a conversation you likely won't be present in. If they can't (or won't care to) defend your point of view, they'll just come back to you saying, well my boss says to do X, so that's what we're doing. And then you'll have a piece that you don't want in your portfolio...

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of using the | character, but not so much the em or en dashes because they will just emphasize the different sizes of the two character types.

You could also use parenthesis around the CSD number in the same typeface. Graphically, they won't stand out too much, and will likely suggest the same relationship between the school and district that your client is trying to achieve by including a comma.